# Moved annotation in PDFView but it moves to the opposite direction

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, pdf, pdfview

I have written the code to move the annotation while dragging the mouse, however the result shows me the annotation moved to the opposite direction of my mouse move trace. It moves with center at the mouse first click point, centrosymmetric opposite... I draw a Rect for the annotaion's bound, but the Rect position is correct...

There is two images show you what happened:

-Before I drag:

[image: Before I drag:]

- After I moved:

[image]

The annotation goes away ....

Below is my code:

```
- (void) mouseDragged: (NSEvent *) theEvent
{


                    // Move annotation.
                    // Hit test, is mouse still within page bounds?
                    if (NSPointInRect([self convertPoint: mouseLoc toPage: activePage],
                                      [[_activeAnnotation page] boundsForBox: [self displayBox]]))
                    {
                        // Calculate new bounds for annotation.
                        newBounds = currentBounds;
                        newBounds.origin.x = roundf(endPt.x - _clickDelta.x);
                        newBounds.origin.y = roundf(endPt.y - _clickDelta.y);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Snap back to initial location.

                        newBounds = _wasBounds;
                    }
// Change annotation's location.
            [_activeAnnotation setBounds: newBounds];

            // Call our method to handle updating annotation geometry.
            [self annotationChanged];

            // Force redraw.
            dirtyRect = NSUnionRect(currentBounds, newBounds);
            dirtyRect.origin.x -= 10;
            dirtyRect.origin.y -= 10;
            dirtyRect.size.width += 20;
            dirtyRect.size.height += 20;
              [super setNeedsDisplay:YES];
            [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:RectPlusScale([self convertRect: dirtyRect fromPage: [_activeAnnotation page]], [self scaleFactor])];

 [super mouseDragged: theEvent];
```

The weird thing is, if the annotation is a image or text, the moved would be correct. It only happens with PDFAnnotationInk class....